# In Flutter App, should each screen have different ad unit for displaying banner?

Tags: android, flutter, admob, banner

I am currently creating a simple game using flutter, and it has many screens. The flow between the screens are as follows:

Intro Screen -> Instructions Screen -> Additional Details Screen -> Game Screen -> Result Screen

I have created an Admob account and I am planning to display Banner Ad in each of the above screens.

Should I create a separate Banner Ad Unit for each screen? Or should I create one Banner Ad Unit for the App and use it in every screen?

Comment: Hi, can you let me know how you actually ended up implementing this?  I'm trying to do the same (ie. I have a few different screens in a game), but I'm unsure of exactly what the correct code is to display the ads from screen to screen

Comment: Hi, I was not completely sure as how to use if I use only one Ad Unit.
My concern is, if the Ad Unit is refreshed multiple times as part of screen transition, will that cause any Ad Policy Violation?
Since I was not sure, I removed Banner Ads from All screens except Game Screen.
Anyways the User was spending most time in the Game Screen in my App.
So as long as the Game Screen is active the Ad Unit displays Ads only in that Screen.

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to the same question.

Answer (score 2):

When you load ad unit and call show

```
..load()
    ..show();
```

ad will display at the bottom of the all app screen until you call

```
dispose();
```

Comment: Behind the scenes if you need display unique ad unit id for each screen you will have to call dispose(); when you exit screen and create new ad for each screen init

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to clarify... if I use only one ad unit, On each screen, i load and show on screen creation and dispose while exiting screen, is this also ok?